# BitBucket Sync with GitHub

Tags: git, bitbucket, teamcity

I have a pipeline setup in TeamCity which runs when there is commit in develop branch.

I am new to TeamCity and this pipeline is existing pipeline.

Now for some new requirement i want to sync the code in this bitbucket repository with new GitHub repository
and this syncing should only happen when TeamCity pipeline run successful.

I need some ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new build configuration with a [Finish build trigger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-finish-build-trigger.html) with "Trigger after successful build only" ticket. In the new build configuration, you could use a [Command line build runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/command-line.html) build step to do the sync between the Bitbucket repository and the Github one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).